# How do I redirect to a variable which contains the location of the output file

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is a very silly and simple thing that I am not sure how to do

I have defined a variable %debugloglocation% in a bat file which contains the location of the file in which I want the output to be written.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

echo Some value that has to be logged > %debugloglocation%
echo Some value that has to be logged > %%debugloglocation%%
echo Some value that has to be logged > "%debugloglocation%"
```

The above does not work. How should I pass the location so that it is recognized when the command runs.

Comment: If the path of the log file or the log itself contains spaces, then you need to enclose it in double quotes. `"%debugloglocation%"`. Also what are the odds that you defined the variable with spaces before and after `=`

Comment: Its the path of the log file. Something like C:\>Users\shashi\projects\debugflie.log

Comment: `set "debugloglocation=path to file"` then `"%debugloglocation%"` with double quotes. When you use it.

Comment: The odds are very high. It was indeed due to space before and after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmd`'s `set` does not want any spaces before or after the `=` This will result in a variable with a trailing space and value with a leading space i.e `set var = val` will result in `%var %` and  `val`

So always `set` string variables with no space between before and after `=` and include double quotes from before the variable to after the values. The correct way would be:

```
set "debugloglocation=C:\some path\logfile.log"
```

always use your variables with double quotes thereafter as well:

```
echo some value logged to "%debugloglocation%"
```

Lastly you can eliminate the multiple re-use of the variable by using parenthesis. (if you are using the method as demonstrated in the post.

```
(
echo some string logged
echo another string logged
echo third string logged
)>"%debugloglocation%"
```